# Unable to clone Unity UI

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to clone the Unity UI from https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui using Atlassian SourceTree as directed at that site.

The SourceTree Clone/Add/Create Repository dialog says *"This is not a valid source path /URL"*.

What am I doing wrong? What is the simplest way to clone the latest Unity UI source?

Comment: This question is not about programming, you have a better chance if you ask this question in another community such as unity forum.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/Unity-Technologies/ui/downloads
You're welcome.

Comment: @Vancete: I said *clone*. I am aware of the download option. I would like to retain the ability to keep my clone up-to-date.

Comment: You need a Mercurial client installed then, probably you cancelled that option at SourceTree install.